# Installing C compiler from source code on shared host server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, python, gcc

I purchased a shared host server at bluehost.

I need to be able to install new python modules, but since I have no root permissions at the server I cannot do that with the current python that is built int and installed.

I am trying to install python in my working space so I will have root privileges ( I cannot use apt-get install - it has to be from source code ).

I downloaded the python tar file and extracted it, and as I try to install it , it throws me the following error:

`configure: error: in '/home2/ofekafsc/python/Python-3.6.5':`

`configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH`

Same thing happens when I try to install GCC

`ofekafsc@ofek-afs.com [~/gcc/objdir]# $PWD/../gcc-8.2.0/configure --prefix=$HOME     /gcc-8.2.0 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,go
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln works... yes
checking whether ln -s works... no, using cp -p
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for libatomic support... yes
checking for libitm support... yes
checking for libsanitizer support... yes
checking for libvtv support... yes
checking for libmpx support... yes
checking for libhsail-rt support... yes
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in '/home2/ofekafsc/gcc/objdir':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH`

As I said, I do not have high enough of privilege to do something such as `sudo apt-get install gcc` , I have to install it from source.

Any help fixing the issue will be happily accepted!!

Comment: You cannot compile GCC without already having a compiler installed. It is a chicken and egg situation. The only way around it is compiling on another system and copying it over, which is effectively what apt-get achieves.